# Sort HKSampleQuery items by Quantity

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hksamplequery

I want to fetch HealthKit quantity data and sort them by quantity value. Is it possible?

I know I can filter them by using `HKPredicateKeyPathQuantity`in the `NSPredicate` but I can't find similar key for sorting

**Example**

```
let type = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight)
let sort = [
  NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: true),
  NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: true),

  //I want one more Sort Item here :(
  //NSSortDescriptor(key: SortIdentifierIdeQuantity, ascending: true)
]

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(HKPredicateKeyPathStartDate) > %@ AND \(HKPredicateKeyPathStartDate) < %@ AND \(HKPredicateKeyPathQuantity) == %@",
  argumentArray:[start, end, value])

let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: type, predicate: predicate, limit: limit, sortDescriptors: sort) { query, res, error in
  completion(res, error)
}

healthKit.executeQuery(query)

}
```

Comment: Seems that you have to sort them after you've done the query.

Comment: yea :( and that's not fun :( of course it's very easy though in swift `res.sort(SortFunc)`

Comment: @Larme It wouldn't work if you set a limit for fetching, then you need to fetch all items in the items you want, sort them, and get only that count as you want

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible to have HealthKit sort the results by date currently.  You should [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/) with Apple for the enhancement that you'd like.